# Renaming two columns or swapping the values? Which one is better?

Tags: sql

I have a table with more than 1.5 million records, in which I have two columns, A and B. Mistakenly the column values of A got inserted into the column B and column B's values got inserted to A.

Recently only we found the issue. What will be the best option to correct this issue? Rename the column names interchangingly (I don't know how it can be possible, since if we nename A to B, when B already exists), or swapping the values contained in the two columns?

Comment: Have you tried a swap in place using an UPDATE query - `UPDATE table SET table.fielda = table.fieldb, table.fieldb = table.fielda`? What's the volume of records?

Comment: If you have indexes on those columns, just renaming them wouldn't solve your problem. Anyways, if you'd go about renaming you'd have to rename A to a temp value first. A -> temp, B -> A, temp -> B.

Comment: Just because I had to google this: `1 lakh` is an indian unit for 100.000. Better use standard metrics on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,
 You can have the below query to swap the columns,

```
UPDATE table_name  SET  A = B, B = A;
```

But you have huge amount of date in this case renaming will be good. But renaming of column name because of data issue is not a right solution. So you can have above update query to update your data.

Before updating take a backup of table which you are updating using the query,

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_bkp AS SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Always have a backup while playing with original data which will not mess up

Answer (score 0):

15 lakh rows aren't a big deal for SQL server. Switching column names have many cons in relational DB such as index, foreign Key and also you may have to do lots of impacts. So, I would like to suggest to go for traditional path. Simply do the update.